# Is it possible to detect and measure the amount of potassium sorbate used to preserve fruit juice?

Tags: solutions, food-chemistry

In a store bought fresh orange juice that is preserved using potassium sorbate is it possible to detect the presence of potassium sorbate and also measure the amount present?
What methods of testing are available?

Comment: A cursory search yields an article published in the International Journal of Bio-Inorganic Hybrid Nanomaterials, an open access journal:   http://ijbihn.iauvaramin.ac.ir/article_4762_a272df290baf6d332ce90920ca415a8b.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The method most likely to yield efficient, cost-effective and quantitative results would be HPLC. Indeed a number of successful  protocol have already been published for determining potassium sorbate in fruit juices:

- [Rapid high-performance liquid chromatography method for the analysis of sodium benzoate and potassium sorbate in foods.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10910223)
- [HPLC and LC-MS/MS methods for determination of sodium benzoate and potassium sorbate in food and beverages: performances of local accredited laboratories via proficiency tests in Turkey.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25577080)

Another method would include juice screening protocol by NMR, but these would require a library to be established (or bought) for quantifying levels.